# How to deploy config.json on elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I thought I could just copy it into .ebextensions and then go

```
config= require("../.ebextensions/config.json")
```

in my lib/server.js, but not so.
Do I have to subscribe to some native config game or can I just have my secret files copied over with

```
eb deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a file onto the list of files in git I have done the below. This is deploying what's on the file system, so I guess this should be improved to fetch a branch from git and zip that up

```
rm package.zip
zip package.zip `echo config/config.json; git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD | awk '{print $4}'`
eb deploy
```

and append to .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

```
deploy:
  artifact: package.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you meant `eb deploy` and not `eb debloy`, make sure you committed these config files.

Comment: I dont want to commit the files, they've got secret keys in.

Comment: you don't need to push the config file, just commit locally. when you issue `eb deploy` only committed files will be taken.

Comment: so what happens then when I push my latest version ?, i dont want these keys going anywhere near a vcs.